# OpenCV Ellipse. Get Corners of ellipse?

Tags: opencv

I have an ellipse from the cv2.ellipse function, that seems to return me the following:

(x,y),(MA,ma),angle = cv2.fitEllipse(cont)

I'm not exactly sure what they correspond to, but I need to use that information to get the corner points of the rotated ellipse as such:

[image]

How exactly can this be acheived. I know what the Major Axis and minor axis correspond to, and i assume the x,y refers to the centroid??? If so, how can I use the angle information provided to calculate the 4 corners?

Comment: Uh, you need help with this simple math?

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32920419) you can find the answer

Comment: The return value is a rotated rect. You can calculate the vertices from it. This example can be reletant: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rotated_ellipses/bounding_rotated_ellipses.html

Comment: i can do the math..provided i understand what the angle refers to

Comment: Hi have you got how to use angle and convert the ellipse to Circle